# Two little computer icon on my menu bar

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

[image]

There are two little computer icons on my menu bar and it keeps blinking. When I click on it, it disappear but again come back in a second. Can anyone please tell me what it is and why is it blinking? Thanks!

Comment: I could have sworn that icon is the screen mirroring icon, which can be turned off in System Preferences -> Displays by unchecking "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available". A Google search, however, shows that this can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am mistaken, this double screen icon is the screen-sharing indicator. This is what it looks like for me in Sierra.

[image]

I can't tell you why its blinking or disappearing, but if you can click on it, you should have the option to see which IP address is connected, and an option to disconnect them. If your computer is managed by someone/some entity (work or school), I would go to their IT office and ask them why this is appearing or if they know anything about it.

If you own and are the only person in control of your computer, then I would suggest you change your User password immediately. Then log out, log back in with the new password. If the icon reappears, then comment below this answer as it might be a virus.

Comment: When I click on it then there is no option. It just disappear and come back again in a second

Comment: @Hemlata then you will want to change your password, log out, then log back in

Comment: Yeah I will change my password and let you know

Comment: I will let you know tomorrow as I turned it off. Thanks

Comment: "This is what it looks like for me in Sierra." Asker is already on Sierra. Note the Siri icon in his screenshot.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy her*

Comment: I turned on my laptop, but now it doesn't show that two little computer icon, instead there is just one computer icon which I believe is screen mirroring. So now I don't have any problem with my mac. Thank you!